# ASP.NET / C# : how to use on focus input field date

Tags: c#, html, date, frontend

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdob" TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="DOB"
             onfocus="(this.type='date')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

The placeholder date should be filled with the date of birth value.

Comment: Why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Comment: `onfocus="(this.type='date')"` <-- This is horrible. Why aren't you using a _proper_ `<input type="date" runat="server">` from `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem for me and now im giving an optional solution for you, i hope this works for you too!

First of all the TextBox needs to be without the *'TextMode="date"'*:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdob" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="DOB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then, you need add to the HTML document this script:

```
<script>
 let txtBox = document.getElementById("txtdob");
 txtBox.addEventListener("focusin", (event) => { txtBox.type = 'date'; });
txtBox.addEventListener("focusout", (event) => {  if (txtBox.value == '') { txtBox.type = 'text'; }  });
</script>
```

With this solution we can see the placeholder if the user hasnt selected a date, and if it has, the input would contain the date select.

Last of all, if the input contains a date, in the server-side we can obtain the value.

Regards,
Marie.